# Creating Dynamic textBox inside PanelGrid using Jsf

Tags: java, jsf

I have an Problem in Creating dynamic inputText inside HtmlPaneGrid in jsf.

### The Thing whic i have done as Follows:

1)I have an DropDown where the User Selects no. of Subjects.
2)Based on the value Selected in dropDown,i have to create inputText inside PanelGrid.
3)So in ajax change event of dropDown,im creating HtmlInputText and add it to htmlPanelGrid and update HtmlPanelGrid
4)This HtmlPanelGrid is binded to backing bean named Subject.

### Problems which im facing:

When i select any one of the value(say for eg:3),No textbox is getting displayed in htmlPanelGrid initially.
When i select another value(eg:2),Previous value is 3(so 3 TextBoxes are getting displayed)
when i select another value(eg:4),Previous value is 2(so 2 TextBoxes are getting displayed)

### Solution Which i need:

When i selct 2,2 textbox should be displayed
3 means 3 textboxes should be displayed and so on.

### My Xhtml Code:(This is part of xhtml code.Not Full Xhtml Code has been pasted)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"htth://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:head></h:head>
<ui:composition template="/templates/common/layout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:body>
            <h:form>
                <p:panel header="Add Subject">
                    <p:growl id="subjGrowl" showDetail="true"></p:growl>
                    <f:view>
                        <p:panelGrid>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <p:row>
                                    <p:column>Degree</p:column>
                                    <p:column>Department</p:column>
                                    <p:column>Academic Session From</p:column>
                                    <p:column>Academic Session To</p:column>
                                    <p:column>Semester</p:column>
                                    <p:column>Number Of Subjects</p:column>
                                </p:row>
                            </f:facet>
                            <p:row>
                                <p:column>
                                    <p:selectOneMenu id="degree"
                                        value="#{subject.entDegree.degreeId}">
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Please Select" itemValue="-1"></f:selectItem>
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{subject.degreeMap}"></f:selectItems>
                                        <p:ajax update="department"
                                            listener="#{subject.handleDegreeChange}"></p:ajax>
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>
                                    <p:selectOneMenu id="department"
                                        value="#{subject.entDepartment.deptId}">
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Please Select" itemValue="-1"></f:selectItem>
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{subject.departmentMap}"></f:selectItems>
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>
                                    <p:inputText value="#{subject.entSubject.academicSessionFrom}"
                                        required="true"
                                        requiredMessage="Academic Session From Required" maxlength="4">
                                        <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true"></f:convertNumber>
                                    </p:inputText>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>
                                    <p:inputText value="#{subject.entSubject.academicSessionTo}"
                                        required="true" requiredMessage="Academic Session To Required"
                                        maxlength="4">
                                        <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true"></f:convertNumber>
                                    </p:inputText>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>
                                    <p:inputText value="#{subject.entSubject.semester}"
                                        required="true" requiredMessage="Semester Required"
                                        maxlength="44"></p:inputText>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>
                                    **<p:selectOneMenu id="noOfSubj" value="#{subject.noOfSubj}">
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{subject.noOfSubjMap}"></f:selectItems>
                                        <p:ajax update="subjPanelGridId" listener="#{subject.updateSubjGrid}"></p:ajax>
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>**
                                </p:column>
                            </p:row>
                        </p:panelGrid>
                        **<h:panelGrid id="subjPanelGridId"
                                        binding="#{subject.subjPanelGrid}">
                        </h:panelGrid>**
                        <f:facet name="footer">
                            <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{subject.seeSubjList}"
                                update="subjGrowl"></p:commandButton>
                        </f:facet>
                    </f:view>
                </p:panel>

            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Backing Bean:
See code marked as bold or **

```
package com.oxford.web.college;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.el.ValueExpression;
import javax.faces.application.Application;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import com.oxford.biz.college.SesnCollegeRemote;
import com.oxford.biz.collegesubjects.SesnSubjectRemote;
import com.oxford.eea.ejb.exception.SystemException;
import com.oxford.entity.campus.EntCampus;
import com.oxford.entity.college.EntDegree;
import com.oxford.entity.college.EntDepartment;
import com.oxford.entity.collegesubjects.EntSubject;
import com.oxford.web.util.DisplayMessage;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Subject implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Subject.class.getName());

    @ManagedProperty("#{error}")
    private ResourceBundle error;

    @ManagedProperty("#{message}")
    private ResourceBundle message;

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{collegeDepartment}")
    private CollegeDepartment collegeDepartment;

    private EntCampus entCampus;

    private EntDegree entDegree;

    private EntDepartment entDepartment;

    private EntSubject entSubject;

    private static Map<String, Object> degreeMap;

    private static Map<String, Object> departmentMap;

    private static Map<Integer, Integer> noOfSubjMap;

    private Integer noOfSubj;

    @EJB
    private SesnSubjectRemote sesnSubjectRemote;

    @EJB
    private SesnCollegeRemote sesnCollegeRemote;

    private List<EntDepartment> listOfDepartment;

    private List<EntDegree> listOfDegree;

    private HtmlPanelGrid subjPanelGrid;

    private Collection gridCollection;

    String errorMsg = null;

    String successMsg = null;

    static {
        degreeMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    public Subject() {
        entDegree = new EntDegree();
        entDepartment = new EntDepartment();
        entSubject = new EntSubject();
        noOfSubjMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for(Integer i=1;i<12;i++){
            noOfSubjMap.put(i, i);
        }
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        loadDegree();
    }

    public static ValueExpression createValueExpression(String valueExpression,
            Class<?> valueType) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        return context
                .getApplication()
                .getExpressionFactory()
                .createValueExpression(context.getELContext(), valueExpression,
                        valueType);
    }

    public void loadDegree() {
        try {
            listOfDegree = sesnCollegeRemote.getDegreeList(getEntCampus()
                    .getCampusId());
            for (EntDegree entDeg : listOfDegree) {
                degreeMap.put(entDeg.getDegreeName(), entDeg.getDegreeId());
            }
        } catch (SystemException sysex) {
            errorMsg = error.getString(sysex.getMessage());
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, errorMsg);
            DisplayMessage.errorMessageUI(errorMsg);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    public void seeSubjList(){
        List subjects = subjPanelGrid.getChildren();
        ArrayList<String> subjList = new ArrayList<String>();
        boolean flag = false;
        String val = null;
outer:      
            for(int i=0;i<subjects.size();i++){
            HtmlInputText htmlText =  (HtmlInputText)subjects.get(i);
            val = (String)htmlText.getValue();
            if(subjList!=null && subjList.size()>0){
                for(int j=0;j<subjList.size();j++){
                    String subject = subjList.get(j);
                    if(subject.equalsIgnoreCase(val)){
                        flag = true;
                        break outer;
                    }
                }
                if(flag==false){
                    subjList.add(val);
                }
            }else{
                subjList.add(val);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(subjList);
        if(flag){
            errorMsg = "The Subject '"+val+"' Should not repeat more than once";
            DisplayMessage.errorMessageUI(errorMsg);
        }
    }

    public void handleDegreeChange() {
        try {
            departmentMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
            listOfDepartment = sesnSubjectRemote.getDepartmentList(
                    entDegree.getDegreeId(), getEntCampus().getCampusId());
            for (EntDepartment entDept : listOfDepartment) {
                departmentMap.put(entDept.getDeptName(), entDept.getDeptId());
            }
        } catch (SystemException sysex) {
            errorMsg = error.getString(sysex.getMessage());
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, errorMsg);
            DisplayMessage.errorMessageUI(errorMsg);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    **public void updateSubjGrid(){
        System.out.println("Inside UpdateSubjGrid method");
        Application app = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication();
        gridCollection = new ArrayList();
        for(int i=0;i<getNoOfSubj();i++){
            HtmlInputText subjectText = (HtmlInputText) app.createComponent(HtmlInputText.COMPONENT_TYPE);
            subjPanelGrid = (HtmlPanelGrid) app.createComponent(HtmlPanelGrid.COMPONENT_TYPE);
            subjPanelGrid.setId("subjGridId-"+i);
            subjectText.setId("subj-" + i);
            subjectText.setValueExpression(
                    "subjName",
                    createValueExpression("#{subject.entSubject.subjName}",
                            String.class));
            gridCollection.add(subjectText);
        }
        subjPanelGrid.getChildren().addAll(gridCollection);
        System.out.println("cc::"+subjPanelGrid.getChildCount());
    }**

    public Map<String, Object> getDegreeMap() {
        return degreeMap;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getDepartmentMap() {
        return departmentMap;
    }

    public EntDepartment getEntDepartment() {
        return entDepartment;
    }

    public void setEntDepartment(EntDepartment entDepartment) {
        this.entDepartment = entDepartment;
    }

    public EntDegree getEntDegree() {
        return entDegree;
    }

    public void setEntDegree(EntDegree entDegree) {
        this.entDegree = entDegree;
    }

    public void setCollegeDepartment(CollegeDepartment collegeDepartment) {
        this.collegeDepartment = collegeDepartment;
    }

    public EntCampus getEntCampus() {
        if (collegeDepartment != null) {
            entCampus = collegeDepartment.getEntCampus();
        }
        return entCampus;
    }

    public ResourceBundle getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(ResourceBundle error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    public ResourceBundle getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(ResourceBundle message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public EntSubject getEntSubject() {
        return entSubject;
    }

    public void setEntSubject(EntSubject entSubject) {
        this.entSubject = entSubject;
    }

    public HtmlPanelGrid getSubjPanelGrid() {
        return subjPanelGrid;
    }

    public void setSubjPanelGrid(HtmlPanelGrid subjPanelGrid) {
        this.subjPanelGrid = subjPanelGrid;
    }

    public Integer getNoOfSubj() {
        return noOfSubj;
    }

    public void setNoOfSubj(Integer noOfSubj) {
        this.noOfSubj = noOfSubj;
    }

    public Map<Integer, Integer> getNoOfSubjMap() {
        return noOfSubjMap;
    }

}
```